# Filter function without using filter() method in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to write a function that is going to filter through an array an return a new filteredArray, but its not working properly with one of the fn functions:

```
    var filter = function(arr, fn) {
        let filteredArray = [];
        for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if(fn(arr[i], i) === true) {
                filteredArray.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return filteredArray;    
};
```

The fn functions are:

- `function greaterThan10(n) { return n > 0; }`
- `function plusOne(n) { return n + 1 }`
- `function firstIndex(n, i) { return i === 0; }`

It's not working with the function number 2, I suppose there is something wrong with the if statement, but I don't know really.
Just started learning programming so please don't eat me.

Comment: `plusOne` does not return a boolean so `fn(arr[i], i)` will never equal true.

Comment: Do you realize that the second function is the only one **NOT** returning a `boolean` result?

Comment: yes, i do realize that but i dont know how to make it work in both cases

Comment: You do need a boolean in order to filter; stated differently, there has to be a test to determine which elements are in or out. What is the test in this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter callback's returned value should be checked to be truthy:

```js
const filter = function(arr, fn, thisArg = arr) {
        const filteredArray = [];
        
        for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if(fn.call(thisArg, arr[i], i)) {
                filteredArray.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return filteredArray;    
}; 

const arr = [-1,0];

console.log(filter(arr, n => n + 1));
```

Comment: so what's the difference between this condition: if(fn(arr[i], i));    and this one: if(fn(arr[i], i) === true);

Comment: @alekam https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: @alekam if my answer solves your problem, you could accept it (the checkbox). that way i'll be rewarded and motivated to help you in the future. that's how stackoverflow works, thanks!